# How to remove button text responsively in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button

I'm very new to Jquery & jquery mobile.  I'm resizing a button so it's responsive to window size.  To be more specific, i'm changing it from iconpos="left" to iconpos="notext" to remove the text on small windows.
I found the following function, which works for me.

```
$(window).on("throttledresize", function() {
  var smallButtons = $(window).width() <= 480;
  $('#menu_toggle').toggleClass('ui-btn-icon-notext', smallButtons);
  $('#menu_toggle').toggleClass('ui-btn-icon-left', !smallButtons);
});
```

But it only works on the window resizing.  Obviously, I'd also like it showing the correct size on pageload, not just resizing.  I found the code below, but I don't know how put them both into 1, more succinct bit of code.

```
$("#page_id").on("pageshow" , function() {
 The Function
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### jQuery Mobile >= 1.4

`.buttonMarkup()` as well as `data-role="button"` are deprecated and will be removed in **1.5**. Instead, classes should be added manually to *Anchor* tag.

- Create a function to manipulate classes of *Anchor*. As of jQM *page events* are now replaced with `pageContainer` events. The new events can't be bound to a specific page, therefore, you need to look for the *Anchor* inside *active page*.

  Note that `$.mobile.activePage` is also deprecated and replaced with `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage")`.

  ```
  function resizeBtn() {
      var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");
      if ($(window).width() <= 480) {
          $("#notext.ui-btn-icon-left", activePage)
              .toggleClass("ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-icon-left");
      } else {
          $("#notext.ui-btn-icon-notext", activePage)
              .toggleClass("ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-icon-notext");
      }
  }
  ```
- Call function on `pagecontainerbeforeshow` event:

  ```
  $(document).on("pagecontainerbeforeshow", resizeBtn);
  ```
- Call function on `throttledresize` event:

  ```
  $(window).on("throttledresize", resizeBtn);
  ```

Note: [`throttledresize`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/throttledresize/) is better than `resize` as it delays firing `resize` event coming from the browser.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/mkPky/)**

---

### jQuery Mobile <= 1.3

You need to use `.buttonMarkup()` if you're using jQuery Mobile 1.3 or lower.

```
$(".selector").buttonMarkup({
  iconpos: "notext"
});
```

- Resize function:

  ```
  function resizeBtn() {
      if ($(window).width() <= 480) {
          $(".selector").buttonMarkup({
              iconpos: "notext"
          });
      } else {
          $(".selector").buttonMarkup({
              iconpos: "right"
          });
      }
  }
  ```
- Call function on `pagebeforeshow`:

  ```
  $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", resizeBtn);
  ```
- Call function on `resize`:

  ```
  $(window).on("resize", resizeBtn);
  ```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/FSX9B/)**

Comment: thanks, I'm trying out your reply atm. Looks good. So jquery1.5 is coming out? I'm only just starting to get the idea of 1.4. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @devsie You're welcome. I've made a minor change `pagecontainerbeforeshow`. I dont think it will come out soon, `.buttonMarkup()` should work normally, but to be on the safe side, considered removed and stick to working functions :)

Comment: Is it also better to use resize than throttled resize?  And if doing things with class="ui-btn" works at the moment and is the way forward, then I'll do things that way, rather than having to change them again in the future.

Comment: @devsie `throttledresize` is better. you can also use `orientationchange` with `throttledresize`.